# How to count the number of items tagged with an acts_as_taggable tag

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

In my app I have a Factoids that are each tagged with different tags. I am attempting to create an index page that lists all the tags and shows how many Factoids are tagged with that tag. I have figured out how to generate the list of tags but cannot figure out how to get the count.

I have three Factoids that are each tagged with the items in parentheses:

- Factoid One ("Red", "Blue)
- Factoid Two ("Red", "Green")
- Factoid Three ("Red", "Blue", "Pink")

What I am trying to do is print out a table that will show the following...

- Red: 3
- Blue: 2
- Green: 1
- Pink: 1

I have this in my view that gives me the names of the tags, but I don't know how to count their occurrences.

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
   <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %>
<% end %>
```

I also managed to write a MySQL query that does it...

```
SELECT tags.name, count(tags.id) AS count
FROM `tags`
LEFT OUTER JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY tags.id;
```

How can I do this query in RoR?

Here is my DB Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140423203020) do

  create_table "factoids", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       :limit => 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  # Foreign Keys and indexes for taggings
   add_index("taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id")
   add_index("taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], :name => "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context")

end
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Sorry but what is DDL?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to do it.

```
<% Factoid.tag_counts.each do |tag| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %></td>
      <td><%= tag.count %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```